# When I want to use the scanner on macOS Ventura, it is necessary to remove and re-add the printer

Tags: printing, ventura, scanning

I own a Samsung Xpress SL-C480W Multifunction Printer, which is connected through WiFi. Since updating my OS to macOS Ventura a couple of months ago, I have been encountering an interesting issue with the scanning functionality. Whenever I try to use the scanner, the scanner button remains greyed out and the system scanning app fails to load the preview. To resolve this issue, I always have to manually remove and re-add the printer via system settings. After this, the scanning functionality works fine for a while. However, if I want to use the scanner again, let's say the next day, the scanner button becomes disabled once again and the only way to fix it is to remove and re-add the printer (restarting of MacBook doesn't help). I have tried updating the printer drivers to the latest version (v3.93, released on Feb 27, 2023), resetting the printing system, and updating the printer firmware, but none of these have been successful.

**A couple of things to note:**

- The printer has a fixed IP address assigned and is always online
- The printing functionality works without any issues all the time
- This problem was not encountered on previous macOS versions

[image: Disabled scanner button]
[image: Empty preview]

**Installed drivers:**
[image: Installed drivers]

Comment: When you say "the next day", do you mean after a restart, or simply after some time with the Mac left on? Have you asked Samsung for support?

Comment: @benwiggy I mean putting the laptop to sleep for a night or so. I haven't contacted Samsung or HP yet

Comment: Keep in mind that the manufacturer may have a single driver package for your device, but there will be two distinct drivers: one for the printer and another for the scanner.  It’s likely the scanner driver isn’t fully compatible with Ventura. Your best bet is to contact the manufacturer to see if there’s a fix for Ventura.

Comment: @Allan you are right, there are two drivers included in the package, and I installed both the scanner and printer drivers. According to the HP website, these drivers were released only for the Ventura OS on Feb 27, 2023 (I had to manually select macOS Ventura to see that version of drivers, otherwise I see only older versions)